# Chromedriver failing on Jenkins (Linux)

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run UI tests on Chrome on Jenkins, and from the error it appears that it is failing to start.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.54 seconds (user: 'UnknownUser-0', output: '1440016601647')
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27 09:10:26'
System info: host: 'abc.xyz.com', ip: '111.222.333.444', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_05'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:139)...
```

The code (in Java) simply tries to instantiate a default instance of Chromedriver, and fails. The following message also shows in the log, which confuses me. It appears that the driver is opening, but stopping immediately?

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf) on port 4601
Only local connections are allowed.
[0.422][WARNING]: PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
Starting ChromeDriver 2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
```

The instantiation is done as:

```
WebDriver webDriver = null;
String chromeDriverLocation = MyCustomPropertyReader.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.binary.location");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverLocation);
final DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

I am able to run the Chromedriver from the command prompt, and I have also checked that all the environment variables that are needed to load it up and indeed available during the instantiation.

Could someone tell me what I might be missing, or if there is a way to obtain more information about the cause of this failure?

Comment: can you post a code snippet how you try to instantiate?

Comment: and which chrome version do you use?

Comment: Chromedriver version is 2.14.313457.

Comment: try without the capabilities or with firefox only - is it working locally ?

Comment: Register your Node with chrome capabilities. few days back i have faced same issue but after registering node for chrome only  works for me.

Comment: What Chrome version is installed?

Comment: It is working fine with Firefox (local and Jenkins). It is working fine with Chrome locally. It's only Chrome on Jenkins that is causing the problem. Also, I am not using any Selenium Grid. I am directly running the browser on xvfb on the build machine itself.

Comment: The Chrome version is google-chrome-stable-44.0.2403.157-1.x86_64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by updating the browser installation, and making sure that both Chromedriver and the Chrome browser can be run from the command prompt.